# Load computed property to populate a nav in Ember/Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

The intent of my code is to have a set of nav locations which contain 'n' lists.  I want to show the # in the navigation for users.  Here is an example:
Search (3)
Qualified (2)
Proposal (6)

My handlebar template from the navigation is as follows:

```
<li>{{#link-to "qualifieditems"}}
      Qualified ({{controllers.qualifieditems.count}})
    {{/link-to}}
</li>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
 App.QualifiedItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     count: function() {
           return this.get('model.length');
     }.property('@each')
)};
```

When I click on the associated nav the ember-data loads and count displays properly.

Getting the data from the router:

```
App.QualifiedItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('qualifieditem');
    }

});
```

The controller for the nav:

```
App.NavController = Ember.Route.extend({
   needs: 'qualifieditems'
});
```

The route for the nav:

```
App.NavRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('qualifieditem');
    }
});
```

So the question remains...when the navigation first loads how can I get {{count}} to update for all nav items?

Thanks in advance for the help! Please let me know if it would be helpful to post any other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Im understanding correctly, try having your computed property also watch when the models load

```
count: function() {
    return this.get('model.length');
}.property('@each', '@each.didLoad')
```

When models finish loading initially, the didLoad flag is changed to true.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jordy Kirkman.  I tried adding the @each.didLoad but it didn't change anything.  I also tried loading the model data in the parent application template which didn't work either. :/